# Two nested sessions in Sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, mariadb

I have outer global session (via Flask-SqlAlchemy) and then within a function, I create another Session which commits some data into database (mariadb backend). The data is, however, not accessible from the outer session, until it closed.

Example:

```
db = SqlAlchemy()

def func():
    s = db.Session()

    with s.no_autoflush:
        obj = models.MyObj(var="test")
        s.add(obj)
        # This inner session is needed because we can't do commits
        # in this session at this point, but still do some inserts
        # via outer session (db.session).

    # Finally we commit inner session to database.
    s.commit()

    # This assertion will fail because data is not accessible
    # in outer session.

    # db.session.close() here would help, but it is not desirable

    assert db.session.query(MyObj).filter_by(var="test").first()
    # -> this fails.
```

How could I create inner session such that it would be within same transaction as outer session (db.session), and thus data committed in inner session would be accessible in outer session?

**Update:**

Here is minimal complete and verifiable example, hope it better explains the problem. Flask/flask-sqlalchemy is not needed.

```
import sqlalchemy as sa

from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker


engine = sa.create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://user:password@mariadb/mydatabase')
#engine = sa.create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:')
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
global_session = Session()

Model = declarative_base()


class MyTable(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'mytable'
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    var = sa.Column(sa.String(length=255), unique=True, nullable=False)


def func():
    internal_session = Session()

    with internal_session.no_autoflush:
        # We add objects to internal_session, but we can't flush them yet (their linkage etc.
        # will be built gradually here)

        obj = MyTable(var="test")
        internal_session.add(obj)

        # At the same time we add some objects via global_session
        obj2 = MyTable(var='test2')

        global_session.add(obj2)
        global_session.commit()

        # If we perform any select query to global_session here, we will face problems later (at [*]).
        # If we comment out this line [*] is fine.
        assert not global_session.query(MyTable).filter_by(var='whatever!').first()

    # Finally we commit inner session to database.
    internal_session.commit()

    # This assertion will fail because data is not accessible
    # in outer session.

    # global_session.close() # here would help, but it is not desirable

    # [*]: this assertion will fail.
    assert global_session.query(MyTable).filter_by(var='test').first()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        Model.metadata.drop_all(engine)
    except:
        pass

    Model.metadata.create_all(engine)

    func()
    print('Ready')
```

Comment: If I understood you correctly, then this seems like a job for a sub transaction, also known as a savepoint. In SQLAlchemy you begin a savepoint with [`Session.begin_nested()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.begin_nested). The reason why the "outer" session doesn't see the committed data until a new transaction begins is that like in MySQL [the default transaction isolation level of MariaDB is repeatable read](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/the-mariadb-library/set-transaction/#isolation-levels).

Comment: The description of "some inserts via outer session" is btw. really vague. Try and produce a [mcve] that describes the problem you have (with not being able to commit at that point).

Comment: If you are tempted to used sub-transactions, I suggest that you have made the architecture overly complex.  Re-think.

Comment: Added minimal, complete, verifiable example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing transaction isolation level to `READ COMMITTED` in the global_session helps.

In the above example, change definition of global_session to the following:

```
global_session = Session(
    bind=engine.execution_options(isolation_level='READ COMMITTED'))
```