Airflow: xcom_pull from a CustomPriorityWeightPlugin
I want to prioritize a run_test_task in DAG B depending on an xcom value from a task get_username in DAG A. DAG B is triggered by a TriggerDagRunOperator trigger_task in DAG A.
The idea is to use Custom Weight Rule that is based on a built-in _DownstreamPriorityWeightStrategy class.
Here is my simplified plugin code:
class CustomPriorityStrategy(_DownstreamPriorityWeightStrategy):

    @provide_session
    def get_weight(self, ti: TaskInstance, session: Session) -> int:
        weight = super().get_weight(ti)
        username = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='get_username', session=session)
        if username == "john":
            weight += 1000
        return weight

Here is the usage:
run_test_task = RunTestOperator(
...
weight_rule="custom_priority_weight_strategy.CustomPriorityStrategy",
...

The trigger_task fails with
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 3901, in _bulk_save_mappings
    persistence._bulk_insert(
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 74, in _bulk_insert
    connection = session_transaction.connection(base_mapper)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 627, in connection
    self._assert_active()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 620, in _assert_active
    raise sa_exc.ResourceClosedError(closed_msg)
sqlalchemy.exc.ResourceClosedError: This transaction is closed

Any idea how to get it work?

I'm the creator of this feature. From my tests, you cannot create a DB session safely in this method because it's called inside the scope of another session which is not provided:
You can try to configure your engine as explained in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46194095/9560594.
I created an issue and a draft PR to fix it. For more information about the bug and to follow the progress of the fix, you can check: https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/40774.

Thanks for the reply, Hussein! I don't think the workaround works for me, so I'll wait for the official solution
